# Why User_login key doesn't work with wp_update_user()

Tags: plugin-development, database, users

I recently was playing with `wp_update_user()`. I faced an issue while changing the `user_login` key. Others like `user_nicename` or other fields change, but `user_login` doesn't change even everything looks good. Here is the code I tried so far.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_new_username_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_new_username_field' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );

function add_new_username_field( $user ) {
    $userData = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
    $username = $userData->user_login;
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'New Username', 'crf' ); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="user-email-wrap">
                <th>
                    <label for="new_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Enter New Username', 'base' ); ?></label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input class="regular-text ltr" type="text" name="new_username" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}

function crf_update_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if (  is_user_logged_in() && ! empty($_POST['new_username'])) {
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'user_login' => $_POST['new_username'] ) );
        // wp_logout();
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? Thanks in advance.
Note: I purged the cache but doesnt work.

Comment: Simply put, because WordPress does not allow changing username. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/135304

Comment: Can we update the username by using $wpdb

Comment: Technically, yes, we can.